# Detecting if we are running in dev mode or in production mode in CloudFlare Worker

Tags: cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I need to know in my worker script if it is running using `wrangler dev` locally
or it is running at cloudflare after `wrangelr publish`.

Is there an environment variable that tells me that, or a request headers?

Code snippet would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There's currently no way to differentiate this, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a builtin variable, but you can populate such info yourself by defining [environments in your wrangler.toml](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/cli-wrangler/configuration#environments)

For example, if we say the topmost `[vars]` are meant to be used in production, we can declare another variable set meant to be used in `local` environment. (the environment name is irrelevant)

```
type = "webpack"
webpack_config = "webpack.config.js"

# these will be used in production
vars = { WORKER_ENV = "production", SENTRY_ENABLED = true }

[env.local]
# these will be used only when --env=local
vars = { WORKER_ENV = "local", SENTRY_ENABLED = false }
```

From then on, if you run your worker locally using

```
wrangler dev --env=local
```

the value of binding `WORKER_ENV` will be populated as defined under `[env.local.vars]`.

By the way, the syntax of `wrangler.toml` above is equivalent to

```
type = "webpack"
webpack_config = "webpack.config.js"

[vars]
  WORKER_ENV = "production"
  SENTRY_ENABLED = true

[env]

  [env.local]

    [env.local.vars]
      WORKER_ENV = "local"
      SENTRY_ENABLED = false
```

Which I believe it's easier to understand

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is an official update for this now (as of November 2022):

> When developing locally, you can create a .dev.vars file in the
> project root which allows you to define variables that will be used
> when running wrangler dev or wrangler pages dev, as opposed to using
> another environment and [vars] in wrangler.toml.

[Cloudflare Workers documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/wrangler/configuration/#environmental-variables)

Answer (score 0):

**This is the way that I am using:**

Create a file `.dev.var` in the root of project and define a variable to detect the environment. In below ex I am using `IS_LOCAL_MODE`

```
IS_LOCAL_MODE=1
```

Now put this variable to Cloudflare to use it in the production environment

```
wrangler secret put IS_LOCAL_MODE
```

Then fill the value is `0`

That's it. Now in your code, to check the mode we will do something like this

```
if(env.IS_LOCAL_MODE == 1){
    console.log("Hello admin, you are in dev mode")
}else{
    console.log("Silence is gold!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What also could work is to use different `build` commands locally and for releases.

For a `CompiledWasm` script, I set the following in `wrangler.toml`:

```ini
[build]
command = "cargo install -q worker-build && worker-build --debug"
```

Now in local development, the following function returns false:

```rust
pub fn is_release() -> bool {
    cfg!(not(debug_assertions))
}
```

Next, in the CI release configuration, I've added a Bash script to overwrite the `--debug` flag:

```bash
 - run: |
     command = "cargo install -q worker-build && worker-build"
     sed -i 's/worker-build --debug/worker-build --release/' wrangler.toml
     if grep -q "worker-build --release" wrangler.toml; then
       echo "Replacement succeeded"
     else
       echo "Replacement failed"
       exit 1
     fi
```

This avoids having to pass the `RouteContext` around in order to check whether the program is in release or development mode.